# Referenced Project Different Output folder

Tags: asp.net, debugging, deployment

I have a web site project with three referenced project.  The question is really simple.  For the refereneced project (say Project A and Project B referenced from Web Site Project).  All I want to do is to reference it in the Web Project but I don't want it to copy to the 'Bin' folder of the web site project.  I want it to copy to a folder that I define.  Is there a way to do that?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you cannot change the ouput path if you build the referenced project. You can change the properties of the reference in the node references by right-clicking => properties, there is a property called copy local which will prevent the copy in the /bin folder. This means you will always reference whatever version of the dll is being pointed at in the Path property